# Undergraduate econometrics - linear model

Tags: econometrics, economics

I have the following model which I am trying to understand:

$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i}+ u_i \sqrt{x_{2i}}_i$

where:

$u_i\sim i.i.d.N(0,\sigma^2)$,

$x_{1i}=x_{2i}+\epsilon_i$,

$\epsilon_i\sim N(0,1)$,

$x_{2i}\sim \chi^2_2$

I am confused about several things:

**(1)** whether there is *heteroskedasticity* in the model. The disturbances seem to be non-spherical, since $\sqrt{x_{2i}}$ enters the error term despite $u_i$ being homoskedastic.

**(2)** whether there is *endogeneity* in the model - the second regressor is clearly correlated with the error. This violates the third Gauss-Markov assumption and thus should produce biased OLS estimates

**(3)** How does $x_{2i}$ following a *chi-squared* distribution with 2 degrees of freedom relate to the model at all and the performance of the chosen estimator?

I would be really grateful if someone could shed light on these points for me, as I am not sure I understand how to deal with this type of model specifications.

Comment: Is your $\sqrt{x_{2i}}_i$ supposed to be $\sqrt{x_{2i}}$?

Comment: When you say "error", are you talking about $\epsilon_i$ or $u_i$?  Do you know $\sigma^2$?

Comment: It is $\sqrt{x_{2i}}_i$. The question is part of a long exercise sheet and it might be a typo, this further confuses me.  When I say error I mean the error of the model - I guess that would be $u_i\sqrt{x_{2i}}+\beta_1 \epsilon_i$. I do not know $\sigma^2$. I just know that it is not $\sigma^2_i$ which makes $u_i$ non sperical.

Comment: I agree with @Henry the expression under the radical looks like a typo which does not give one a huge amount of confidence in the rest of the exercise.

Comment: @mdewey This might be the case, however I am not so interested in solving the exercise as I am in understanding this type of model specification. That is, assuming the second $i$ is a typo, is such a model heteroskedastic and endogenous? I have not come across in any of my textbooks a model where the error term is multiplied with a function of a regressor, which is in turn a function of the other regressor. I simply do not know what this implies for the gauss markov assumptions.

Comment: If you are saying $u_i\sqrt{x_{2i}}$ is part of the error term, then it is not independent of $x_{2i}$ and so you have endogenicity.  Its variance will be larger when $x_{2i}$ is larger and so you also have heteroscedasticity.  Incidentally, your model could perhaps be written $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_3 x_{i}+\epsilon_i+ u_i \sqrt{x_{2i}}_i$ with $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma_\epsilon^2)$  where $x_i=x_{2i}$ with $x_{1i}$ unnecessary.

Comment: Besides all the other complications, it is unclear whether $x_{2i}$ is observed or rather latent (given the error-in-variables construction with $x_{1i}$). If the latter, the regression error term is $u_i \sqrt{x_{2i}}$, but $u_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $x_{2i} \sim \chi^2_{2}$. Thus [$\sqrt{x_{2i}}$ follows a Rayleigh distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1059938) with $\sigma=1$. That's a very odd model setup.

Comment: @Durden $x_2i$ has to be observed if it is included in the model as a regressor doesn't it? We are supposed to use different model setups (including this one) to run simulations and see how different estimators perform. So in this sense, we know both $x_{1i}$ and  $x_{2i}$. What puzzles me further is that the betas from ols on this model come out unbiased and consistent (apart from beta 2 which diverges from the true value as n grows! ) which should not be the case in theory...

Comment: Your $x_{1i} = x_{2i} + \epsilon_i$ equation looks very much like a measurement model, relating the "measurement" $x_{1i}$ to its underlying (latent) equivalent $x_{2i}$. Also, you're giving $x_{2i}$ a distribution, which is not something we'd typically do with *observable* variables.

Comment: Oh I see, I did't think of it this way. But even if this is the case, $x_{1i}$ would still be correlated with the error term and hence I'd have endogeneity. So I still don't understand why my ols estimates seem to be unbiased and consistent. In any case, I made more sense of this setup, so thank you @Durden and Henry for your comments!